# How should I understand in a vuejs template <Menu as="<div"

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I am rather new to Vuejs which I use with tailwind.
There is some markup I have trouble understanding such as

```
<Menu as="<div>"
```

I guess the tag  may be considered as a  tag but if so, why to use this ?
I cannot find an explanation anywhere.
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `as="div"`, according to the [component api](https://headlessui.dev/vue/menu#menu) in headlessUI framework :

> The element or component the `Menu` should render as.

That means the root rendered element taken by `Menu`

Comment: Thank you. Yes it should be as="div" . I will have a look at this api

Comment: You are welcome, please don't forget to vote my answer